# Chrome extensions: Script running many times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a *popup.html* which executes *popup.js* which communicates with *getchanges.js*.

HTML -

```
<html>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="value" id="myId" />
        <button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var btn=document.getElementById("submitButton");
    var id;
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        id=tabs[0].id;
    });
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        var myId=document.getElementById("myId").value;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "getchanges.js"}, function(){
            console.log("sending");
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(id, {myId: myId});
        });
    });
});
```

getchanges.js -

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("script");
});
```

Problem - On every *submitButton* click I am getting correct number of **clicked** and **sending** in console but I am getting **script** in console more than expected. Actually it logs **script** number of times I have pressed *submitButton*.

Eg. When I press *submitButton* second time, it logs **script** twice. Similarly on third time, it logs thrice.

What should I do to log **script** in console only once upon a single *submitButton* click.

Any idea towards solution is appreciated.

Comment: See [Chrome extension: Checking if content script has been injected or not](//stackoverflow.com/a/34529045)

Comment: @wOxxOm What exactly should I be looking in there?

Comment: There's an example how to prevent double execution in content script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome.tabs.executeScript is misleading, it doesn't execute the script, it injects it into the content page and then it runs there. So each time you press submit, you're injecting another copy and hence adding another event listener.

Just arrange it so the script is only injected once in the DOM loaded event.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47127060/4428377) by Troy Wray, I re-arranged my script and it worked.

Now my popup.js looks like -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var btn=document.getElementById("submitButton");
    var id;
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        id=tabs[0].id;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "getchanges.js"}, function(){
            console.log("injecting");
        });
    });
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var myId=document.getElementById("myId").value;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(id, {myId: myId}, function(result){
            //console.log(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Now it is working as required.